# How to write the pop-up HTML in a Crossrider extension?

Tags: crossrider

How do you write the pop-up HTML in a Crossrider extension?

What triggers it and how do you add an image, eg if you want to show a logo in the pop-up with some text, do you leave the `extension.js` since you will be writing all the codes in the pop-up HTML?

I am so confused here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In general, Crossrider popups can be created with a few simple steps, as follows:

1. On the (**Settings** >) **Browser Buttons** page, enable the extension button for the browsers you want to support
2. In the *background.js* file:

   1. Set the button icon using [appAPI.browserAction.setResourceIcon](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.browserAction-method-setResourceIcon) (Note: don't forget to add the icon to the extension's resources)
   2. Set the popup details using [appAPI.browserAction.setPopup](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.browserAction-method-setPopup)

      > appAPI.browserAction.setPopup({resourcePath:'popup.html', height: 300, width: 300});
3. Create the template popup HTML that is specified as the **resourcePath** property in step 2.2.

   On the **Edit Code** page, right-click on the **Resources** folder, point to **Create**, click **Popup**, and then specify the name for the popup file (e.g. *popup.html*).

At this point, you have a fully functional popup button that is triggered whenever the extension button is clicked.

To customize your popup, simply add HTML, CSS, and JS to the **popup.html** in a similar way to a regular HTML page adding remote resources using standard HTML tags. Use our **crossriderMain** function, as defined in our popup template, to add files from your extension's **Resources** folder. For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- This meta tag is relevant only for IE -->
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function crossriderMain($) {
        // Note: don't forget to add the files to the extension's resources
        // Load resource CSS
        appAPI.resources.includeCSS('style.css');
        // Load resource JS
        eval(appAPI.resources.get('script.js'));
        // Load resource image
        $('#myImg').attr('src', appAPI.resources.get('myImg.png'));
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
Hello World!
<img id="myImg">
</body>
</html>
```

If you need any assistance with any specific issues, please feel free to email our support (support@crossrider.com).

[**Disclaimer**: I am a Crossrider employee]

Comment: So you would modify content in the pop up using jquery just as you normally do in dom, for example if you are planning to give back progress of something that is being carried out?? I also had an issue adding an image to the pop up, al try what ave seen above from you example.

Comment: Correct, you can use jquery within the crossriderMain function to manipulate the DOM. Regarding the image issue, if can you provide your code AND confirm that you uploaded the image to the Resource folder, I am happy to help you. [Disclaimer: I am a Crossrider employee]

Comment: If you need a live example, you can check out Crossrider's Popup demo: http://crossrider.com/apps/24802/ide